# An inequality similar to the Hölder Inequality

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $\ p,q \geq 1$ and $\dfrac{1}{p} + \dfrac{1}{q} < 1$.  I want to show that if $f \in L^p$ and $ g\in L^q$, then $fg \in L^\frac{pq}{p+q}$. Also, $||fg||_\frac{pq}{p+q}\leq ||f||_p\cdot||g||_q$.

How do I do it? I tried using Hölder's Inequality, but it is not clear how to apply it in this particular problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Hölder with exponents $p'$ and $q'$ designed to make $[|f|^{pq/(p+q)}]^{p'}=|f|^p$, etc.

Comment: Using this, I see that $(\int |f|^p |g|^q)^{\frac{pq}{p+q}} \leq ||f||_p ||g||_q$, but still I cannot show that $||fg||_{\frac{pq}{p+q}} \leq (\int |f|^p |g|^q)^{\frac{pq}{p+q}}$.

Comment: Start with $\int |fg|^{pq/(p+q)}$, write it as $\int f'g'$, where $f'=|f|^{pq/(p+q)}$ and $g'=|g|^{pq/(p+q}$, and the apply Hölder' inequality with $p'$ and $q'$ as indicated in my earlier answer.

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thank you very much! I was already doing that, but hadn't realized the problem was already solved!